# Soft Question about reading differential equations.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In my differential equations class, we are reading from "The Qualitative Theory for Differential Equations." My question is about one of the requirements for uniqueness of a solution to a differential equation.

An example from the book writes:

$y'=\alpha y$

and I can understand this from my computational diffyq class, $y(t)=ce^{\alpha t}$, but then the book rewrites this as: $f(t,y)=\alpha y$, as a function of the (t,y) plane.

This is where my understanding breaks down. Perhaps I am overthinking it or intimidated, but I cannot come to terms with "the t-y plane". I am used to thinking of it as the XY plane, as in elementary school, yet $y(t)=ce^{\alpha t}$ is always unequal to zero, so how could it be thought of as an axis to a plane? The book also mentions regions in (n+1)-dimensional euclidean space, where the variables are functions of t.

Anything that might help my intuition is welcome, thanks!

Comment: Why do you say that $y(t)=ce^{\alpha t}$ is always unequal to zero? Is not $c$ an arbitrary constant?  Can't $c$ equal zero? Is the constant function $y=0$ not a solution of the differential dquation $y'=\alpha t$? Ans what is your objection to using $t$ instead of $x$ as the independent variable, especially when the independent variable is time?

Answer (score 1):

In some application of differential equation the independent variable is time. For example if you put your money in the bank and the interest rate is $5$ percent per year, the differential equation is $y'=0.05y$ where y=y(t) is the balance at time $t$.

If you want to graph your solution you will get a curve, which is the graph of $y=y(0)e^{0.05 t} $ and you graph it in the $ty$ plane instead of $xy$ plane.

Now if you have a system of differential equations you may have to consider the $tY$ space where$ Y=(y_1,y_2,..., y_n)$ is a vector whose components are functions of $t$

In summary, instead of $x$ you can call your independent variable $t$ or whatever else depending the model that you are working on.

Comment: what about in the example where $f(t,y)=\alpha y$?

Comment: Then $\alpha$ is the rate and  $t$   is the independent variable. If $t$ does no show in the $RHS $ of your  equation , do not worry about it, it makes it easier to solve. ( and we do not see the  time anyway )